# readObject() EOFexception on Client

Tags: java

```
do
        {
            try
            {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
            {
                showMessage("\nI don't know that object type");
            }
        }
        while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
```

Hello everyone, 
I had trouble understanding how to solve this question so I had to send it here.
I would like to get a serious answer on what to do to fix this code.
Basically when I am reading on what server has sent me I get an EOFException on readObject(). 
My server sends message and client reads it

```
output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
            output.flush();
```

My questions is should I use writeUTF and readUTF or can I make somehow readObject and writeObject work ?

Answer (score 0):

EOFException can occur in ObjectOutputStream if you mix write/read modes e.g. if you writeUTF and readObject.

However, I would use writeUTF/readUTF with DataOutputStream and DataInputStream as these are much simpler.